# Why do I have files like my_file.txt~ showing in the terminal?

Tags: 14.04, bash, files

I have files like `my_file.txt` in my folder in ubuntu system, but when I `ls` on the command line terminal it shows `my_file.txt~` and not `my_file.txt`. I need to read this file using R program which is causing it to read the file incorrectly in R. What could be the reason it show .txt~ extension in my terminal?

Comment: @Panther It's a different problem. My whole directory is cluttered with `.txt~` files and none of them are `.txt` (the actual files) showing in terminal. Why?

Comment: @dessert How do I get rid of those files?

Comment: First figure out what editors are making the backups and disable auto backup. Then use find

Answer (score 0):

If you've edited the file in a text editor like [GNU emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) then the `.txt~` version of the file is created when you save any new edits, the `~` version is the last revision of the file before your current edits were saved.

I'm not sure which text editor you‘re using but most likely these files have come from someone editing them in a text editor either emacs or another editor.